# Angular Component display [object Object] instead of value

Tags: html, json, angular, typescript

I have 2 input fields for name and age, I need to display every user I add in a list. However, instead of the name and age, the following is displayed:

[object Object]'s age is [object Object].

My app.Component.ts file is:

```
export class AppComponent {
     users = []

      addUser(name: string , age : number): void {
       const uniqueId = Math.random().toString(16)

       const newUser = {
           id: uniqueId,
           name,
           age
       }
       this.users.push(newUser)
   }
}
```

the userList.component.ts file is:

```
export class UsersListComponent 
{
    @Input() users;
    @Output() adduserEvent = new EventEmitter<Object>()
    newUsername: string = ''
    newUserAge: number = 0

   setNewUserName (userName : string): void {
       this.newUsername = userName
   }

   setNewUserAge (userAge : string): void {
       this.newUserAge = parseInt(userAge)
   }

   addUser(): void {
       console.log(this.newUsername, this.newUserAge)
       this.adduserEvent.emit({name: this.newUsername , age: this.newUserAge})
       this.newUsername = ''
           this.newUserAge = 0
       }
}
```

and the HTML parts are:

In app:

```
<app-users-list [users] = users (adduserEvent)="addUser($event, $event)"></app-users-list>
```

In userList:

```
<input #userName type="text" (change)="setNewUserName(userName.value)" [value] = "newUsername"/>
<input #userAge type="number" (change)="setNewUserAge(userAge.value)" [value] = "newUserAge"/>
<button (click) = "addUser()">Add new User</button>
<div *ngFor = "let user of users" class="user-container">
    <span>{{user.name}}'s age is {{user.age}}</span>   
</div>
```

Comment: Your User array in the App component and the template you're showing belong to user-list component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case **(adduserEvent)="addUser($event, $event)"**
value of $event value will be {name: this.newUsername , age: this.newUserAge} and that is an object. When you pass that object, ofc the name and age parameters in addUser function would be objects and not strings...

You should change either to: **(adduserEvent)="addUser($event. name, $event.age)"** or to change addUser function to accept object a a parameter:

(adduserEvent)="addUser($event)"

```
  addUser(user: {name: string, age: number}): void {
   const uniqueId = Math.random().toString(16)

   const newUser = {
       id: uniqueId,
       user.name,
       user.age
   }
   this.users.push(newUser)
```

}

Comment: the first solution worked actually, but the second didn't. Thank you